# Measure-Theoretic Importance Sampling: Do we need equivalence of measures?

Tags: probability, bayesian, sampling, simulation, importance-sampling

Let $\pi$ and $\mu$ be the target and proposal measures on $(X, \mathcal{X})$ respectively, with $\pi \ll \mu$. Suppose $\lambda$ is the reference measure on $(X, \mathcal{X})$ and that $\pi\ll \lambda$ and $\mu\ll\lambda$ with densities
$$
\frac{d \pi}{d\lambda} = \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\pi \, d\lambda} \qquad \qquad \frac{d \mu}{d \lambda} = \frac{\tilde{p}_\mu}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\mu d\lambda}
$$
I would now like to find the usual expression for the Importance Sampling weights. For this, I consider the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\pi$ with respect to $\mu$
$$
\begin{align}
W = \frac{d \pi}{d \mu} 
&= \frac{d \pi}{d \lambda} \frac{d \lambda}{d \mu} && \text{Chain rule requires $\pi \ll\lambda \ll \mu$} \\
&= \frac{d \pi}{d\lambda} \left(\frac{d \mu}{d \lambda}\right)^{-1} && \text{This requires $\lambda \ll \mu$ and $\mu \ll \lambda$ i.e. equivalence} \\
&= \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\pi \, d\lambda} \cdot \left(\frac{\tilde{p}_\mu}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\mu d\lambda}\right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi}{\tilde{p}_\mu} \cdot \left(\frac{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\mu d \lambda}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\pi d\lambda}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Which makes sense because this agrees with the usual set-up. However, for this to work, we must have $\mu$ and $\lambda$ equivalent, but surely this is not necessarily the case in practice?

> Is this derivation correct?  I.e. do we need $\mu\ll\lambda$ and $\lambda \ll\mu$ to get our usual Importance Sampling weights?

Comment: Replacing $\text d\lambda$ with $\text d\lambda$ restricted to the support of $\text d\mu$ should solve the problem, shouldn't it?

Comment: The restriction of $\text d\lambda$ is set to be zero outside the support of $\text d\mu$, which makes both measures equivalent.

Comment: If $A\in\mathcal B$ is such that $A\subset\text{supp}(\mu)$ and $\lambda(A)>0$ then $\mu(A)>0$.

Comment: @Xi'an Now I get it! Since $\mu$ admits a density with respect to $\lambda$ we must have $\mu \ll \lambda$. One cannot expect $\lambda \ll \mu$ to be true in general. However, we define $\lambda'$ to be the restriction of $\lambda$ on the support of $\mu$
$$
\text{supp}(\mu) = \left\{A\in\mathcal{X}\, :\, \mu(A) > 0\right\}
$$
This means that $\lambda'$ gives measure $0$ to every set $B$ outside of the support of $\mu$, i.e. any set $B$ such that $\mu(B) = 0$. This is exactly saying $\mu(B) = 0 \implies \lambda'(B) = 0$ so $\lambda' \ll \mu$.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you!